# Unable to login offline: no such user - Spotify

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to create a spotify application, but when doing the login I get a weird error message:
*19:28:57.916 I [offline_authorizer.cpp:289] Unable to login offline: no such user

```
int main() {

    sp_session *sp;
    sp_error err;

    sp_session_callbacks callbacks;
    callbacks.logged_in = &logged_in;
    callbacks.notify_main_thread = &notify_main_thread;
    callbacks.music_delivery = &music_delivery;
    callbacks.metadata_updated = &metadata_updated;
    callbacks.play_token_lost = &play_token_lost;
    callbacks.log_message = &log_message;
    callbacks.end_of_track = &end_of_track;

    sp_session_config config;
    config.api_version = 10;
    config.cache_location = "/tmp/libSpotify";
    config.settings_location = "/tmp/libSpotify1";
    config.application_key = g_appkey;
    config.application_key_size = g_appkey_size;
    config.user_agent = "Name_of_client";
    config.callbacks = &callbacks;
    config.tracefile = "/tmp/trace";

    err = sp_session_create(&config, &sp);

    g_sess = sp;

    if (SP_ERROR_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create session: %s\n",
                sp_error_message(err));
        exit(1);
    }
    sp_session_login(sp, username, password, 0);
    printf("Exiting");
    return 0;
}
```

I've been using the Jukebox example, but can't seem to get it to work. I can login to my account and play music on the computer using the account.

Comment: are you using this with a spotify premium account?

Comment: yes, i'm using premium. But I can't really get why it would say offline login...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call sp_session_process_events() in your main thread's event processing loop. Found this in [Connected to spotify AP, but GetConnectionState(), user not yet logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086813/connected-to-spotify-ap-but-getconnectionstate-user-not-yet-logged-in) so check that out for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
19:28:57.916 I [offline_authorizer.cpp:289] Unable to login offline: no such user
```

The above should not be a problem and is generally caused by libspotify trying to log in the user "off-line" using (missing) cached credentials before the actual on-line login takes place. I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Okay, so it might be something else not going through to the libSpotify connection. 
Have anyone tried having spotify iinstalled in Linux (ubuntu|xubuntu) and run the libSpotify as well?