# Connected to spotify AP, but GetConnectionState(), user not yet logged in

Tags: android, android-ndk, spotify

I am doing spotify streaming in android, using official libspotify.so.
Now i can connect to spotify AP, but the status is still not logged in.

Initialise() successfully, callback_notify_main_thread is called

```
10-26 14:00:05.925: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:Initialise
10-26 14:00:05.935: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:callback_notify_main_thread
10-26 14:00:05.935: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:Initialise:end:0
```

login() is called "successfully", callback_log_message shows it cannot login offline, the  logging status is false

```
10-26 14:00:05.935: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:login
10-26 14:00:05.935: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:OnLogMessage, data: 11:00:05.943 I [offline_authorizer.cpp:297] Unable to login offline: no such user
10-26 14:00:05.945: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:login:end:0
10-26 14:00:05.945: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:IsLoggedIn:false
```

More callback_log_messages are coming in different thread

```
10-26 14:00:05.945: PID:1419, **TID:1427** D/MBS: --- Session:OnLogMessage, data: 11:00:05.951 I [ap:1752] Connecting to AP ap.spotify.com:4070
10-26 14:00:05.965: PID:1419, **TID:1427** D/MBS: --- Session:OnLogMessage, data: 11:00:05.969 I [network.cpp:438] Connecting to 78.31.8.42:4070
10-26 14:00:06.015: PID:1419, **TID:1427** D/MBS: --- Session:OnLogMessage, data: 11:00:06.014 I [ap:1226] Connected to AP: 78.31.8.42:4070
```

after coonected to spotify ap,  logging status is still false, no callback_logged_in is called

```
10-26 14:33:38.095: PID:1419, TID:1419 D/MBS: --- Session:IsLoggedIn:false
```

any idea, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

need to call sp_session_process_events() in main thread after notify_main_thread. from https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/faq/

> What is the the notify_main_thread callback? Why is it needed?
>   This callback is invoked from any thread when the main thread need to awaken to process events and in turn deliver callbacks to your application.

then login call back will be called. and check the GetConnectionState(), it is 4.
  SP_CONNECTION_STATE_OFFLINE    = 4  ///< Logged in in offline mode

Comment: sp_session_process_events() needs to be responded in main thread.
sometimes the callback_notify_main_thread is called from main thread, if it is called from other thread, then need to wake up the main thread first.how to design the codes to call sp_session_process_events()? in spotify's jukebox, it uses infinite loop to wait for the main thread call back, it will be always there.
But if the main thread is also doing the android java codes, like listening to events, change the UI, how to design it is a good way? use an independent thread to do a infinite loop waiting there?